# MySQL where value NOT in SET datatype field

Tags: mysql

I should start by saying that I know how to check for the existence of a `SET` datatype, however, I'm now trying to negate the lookup, which doesn't seem to work, so I'm assuming I'm doing something stupid.

I've got this field:

```
| billing_payment_prefs  | set('allow_admin','allow_trans','allow_supress','requires_nag')       | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
```

And all records are currently NULL for said field. I have 3000+ records in this table, and running the following query:

```
mysql> select count(id) from customers where billing_payment_prefs not like '%allow_trans%';
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

... I get `0` instead of the 3000 plus (which I'd expect, as they're all NULL). Now, I'm obviously unsure of how to look up a `NOT LIKE` against a SET field, but I had assumed (incorrectly, by the looks of things) that this would work, even though [MYSQL DEV](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) doesn't mention it.

Any help, is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried `select count(id) from customers where billing_payment_prefs not like '%allow_trans%' or billing_payment_prefs is null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting no records back is because MySQL (as well as most RDBMS) treat `NULL` as a special value.  Comparing some text against `NULL` does not yield a true or false, but rather yields `NULL`, because comparing an unknown value against a known value yields an unknown result.

To make the logic in your query work, you can add a condition for `NULL` checks:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM customers
WHERE billing_payment_prefs NOT LIKE '%allow_trans%' OR
      billing_payment_prefs IS NULL
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. I had assumed that was the case, just needed someone more knowledgeable to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

You have to *explicitly* check for `NULL` values:

```
select count(id) 
from customers 
where billing_payment_prefs not like '%allow_trans%' or 
      billing_payment_prefs is null;
```

This holds for all data types, not only enumerations.